# How to use custom variables in serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a serializer that uses the variables from my model and also counts how many data of the same id is found in the table.

I have created this, but it doesn't work:

```
class WebsiteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    item_nr = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = URL
        fields = (
            "id",
            "item",
            "status",
            "item_nr "
        )

    def get_item_nr (self, obj):
        obj.item_nr = Items.objects.filter(item_id=self.context.get(id)).count()
        return obj.item_nr
```

This is the error that I get:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `item_nr`
>   on serializer `WebsiteSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `URL` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'URL' object has no attribute 'item_nr '.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Please provide models definition for more context. Thanks.

Comment: There is a space in "item_nr ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items_nr` will be a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) not `IntegerField`
The field will be automatically assigned data type based on what you return in `get_item_nr`.

```
class WebsiteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    item_nr = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = URL
        fields = (
            "id",
            "item",
            "status",
            "item_nr "
        )

    def get_item_nr (self, obj):
        obj.item_nr = Items.objects.filter(item_id=self.context.get(id)).count()
        return obj.item_nr
```

Comment: @ottomd If the solution works for you, kindly upvote and accept the answer.